# how conditionally render markup based on model data?

Tags: knockout.js

I have json data as follows:

```
var js = {
    headers: [{
        name: 'Id',
        editable: false
    }, {
        name: 'Name',
        editable: true
    }],
    data: [
        [1, 'Ajay'],
        [2, 'Ankur']
    ]
};
```

Goal is to generate a table element from the above data. The header contains info which tells if the data in that particular column has to be rendered as static text or if it has to be rendered in a text box (via the `editable` property).

How to write the knockout data-bind for this scenario?

This is how far I've got:

```
<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
    <thead>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: Headers">
            <th data-bind="text: $data.name"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Rows">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: $data">
            <!-- what to do here...?!!! -->               
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a fiddle I've tried to work with: http://jsfiddle.net/deostroll/mLLrk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use KO inline statements:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Rows">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: $data">               

            <!-- ko if: someCondition -->
             <td>Some Content</td>
            <!-- /ko --> 


        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

See example [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) (go to the end)

**UPDATE:**

OK, i see the problem, since you are in a for loop you loose context of the ViewModel, so in order to call a VM attribute you need to use the `$root`:

```
<!-- ko if: $root.renderTextBox -->
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mLLrk/1/

Comment: It ain't working the way you want it to...this fiddle I am trying to achieve something different but on the same lines... http://jsfiddle.net/deostroll/mLLrk/

Comment: I've made another fiddle. Why is not the two-way binding not working now... If you enter something in any textbox the corresponding array element isn't getting updated... http://jsfiddle.net/deostroll/CVmWY/

Comment: The way observableArrays work is that they only update if a model was added/removed from the array, they do not update the actual model values. You need to define the inner model to be observable.

Comment: Note if you are putting something inside the `<!-- ko if: -->` statement that would result in a URL being fetched that it will still be fetched by the browser even if the express evaluates to false. the markup will be removed but it is already too late - can cause a performance problem if you're using video for instance. in this case you could do something like a template where the template name is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

If you want to decide if an attribute should be on or off, you can create a binding like this,

```
data-bind="attr: {contenteditable: editable}"
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SrJq8/1/)

---

If you would like to render different HTML depending on a value, you can use virtual elements (useful inside tables).

```
<!-- ko if: editable -->
    <input type="text" />
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: editable -->
    <span></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8PFrA/)

Answer (score 0):

If what you're conditionally showing would result in a URL fetch then note that the URL will be fetched by your browser before knockout has had a chance to hide it.

You can do something like this to load a template conditionally

```
    <figure data-bind="template: { name: supportsVideo ? 'unveil-video' : 'unveil-image-sequence' }"></figure>

    <script type="text/html" id="unveil-video">           
        <video class="benefit-video" data-crossorigin="anonymous" preload="auto">
            ...
        </video>
    </script>

    <script type="text/html" id="unveil-image-sequence">
        <div class="unveil-image-sequence"></div>
    </script>
```